# work sun.misc.BASE64Encoder/Decoder for getting byte[]

Tags: java

I am trying to use sun.misc.BASE64Encoder/Decoder, but this code:

```
(new sun.misc BASE64Encoder()).encode(new    
    sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer("test string XML:"))
```

returns "test/string/XML/" 
I am embarrassed

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Don't use `sun.misc` or `com.sun` classes. They are not guaranteed to be consistent between different versions of the jre.

Use [commons-codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html) `Base64.encodeBase64(..)` and `Base64.decodeBase64(..)`

Comment: hehe.. I sent my recent project in which sun.misc.BASE64Encoder/Decoder used to a customer. Didn't know about inconsistency in different jre's. I hope it's a rare issue.

Comment: It's actually been working fine since JDK 1.1, but it's still ugly to use internal APIs. From a purely practical standpoint, you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: Why not to use sun.* packages: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html

Answer (score 15):

Use Class:

```
javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter
```

**It has 2 methods of interest:**

```
public static byte[] parseBase64Binary( String lexicalXSDBase64Binary )
public static String printBase64Binary( byte[] val )
```

Comment: I've been looking for a reliable way to convert Base64 using the native libraries for days now. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You first *decoding* the string "test string XML:", which isn't really valid Base64, since it contains spaces and a colon, none of which are valid B64 characters. I think that you meant to *encode* then *decode*, like this:

```
(new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode("test string XML:"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
String s = "Hello world";
new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(s.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

Even better, use the commons utils as the previous answer suggested.  Only use sun.misc.Base64Encoder if you can't afford to add the external dependency on another jar.