# Data Truncated After Encryption Not Received at Client

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, rsa

code to send data to server

```
BufferedReader keyRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
OutputStream ostream = sock.getOutputStream(); 
 PrintWriter pwrite = new PrintWriter(ostream, true);
 // receiving from server ( receiveRead  object)
 InputStream istream = sock.getInputStream();
 BufferedReader receiveRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(istream));

 String receiveMessage, sendMessage;               
 while(true)
 {
    sendMessage = keyRead.readLine();  // keyboard reading
    String enc = crypt.encrypt(sendMessage, serverPublicKey);
    System.out.println("sending to server: "+enc);
    pwrite.println(enc);       // sending to server
    pwrite.flush();                    // flush the data
    if((receiveMessage = receiveRead.readLine()) != null) //receive from server
    {
        //System.out.println(crypt.decrypt(receiveMessage, clientPrivateKey)); // displaying at DOS prompt
        System.out.println(receiveMessage);
    }         
  }
```

**output** after encryption looks like below on console

```
sending to server: YRJ7ZNgqSQ56nGc8ff7ktoybYEohQJS2R+Vh3YN1YfHipUS64MyFrrYAzL4CiTPv2WF7zvaJst1A
qsiPsv3/1Q==
```

code to receive on server

```
      BufferedReader keyRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
      // sending to client (pwrite object)
      OutputStream ostream = sock.getOutputStream(); 
      PrintWriter pwrite = new PrintWriter(ostream, true);

      // receiving from server ( receiveRead  object)
      InputStream istream = sock.getInputStream();
      BufferedReader receiveRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(istream));

      String receiveMessage, sendMessage;               
      while(true)
      {
        if((receiveMessage = receiveRead.readLine()) != null)  
        {
           //System.out.println(crypt.decrypt(receiveMessage, serverPrivateKey));
            System.out.println(receiveMessage);
        }         
        sendMessage = keyRead.readLine(); 
        String enc = crypt.encrypt(sendMessage, clientPublicKey);
        System.out.println("sending to clinet: "+enc);
        pwrite.println(enc);             
        pwrite.flush();
      }
```

but data is received like

```
YRJ7ZNgqSQ56nGc8ff7ktoybYEohQJS2R+Vh3YN1YfHipUS64MyFrrYAzL4CiTPv2WF7zvaJst1A
```

rest of

```
qsiPsv3/1Q==
```

is received when i send something from server to client, please help me locate the problem, due to truncated data the decryption fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not only encrypt the input but you also Base64 encode the encrypted bytes. Your Base64 encoder inserts line breaks every 76 characters, which is the standard for [Base64 transfer encoding for MIME (RFC 2045)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). That is why on the server side your `readLine()` only reads in the first 76 characters.

You need to configure your Base64 encoder to not add line breaks.

Comment: thanks for your time, any suggestions how to do that?

Comment: @dakait, check the API doc of the encoder you are using.

Comment: for future ref, this answer helped me http://stackoverflow.com/a/20587169/1679410