# Store a Blob from Java to BD: Data size bigger than max size for this type when is clearly not

Tags: java, oracle, jakarta-ee, oracle11g, blob

Ok, here we go...

I am trying to call a Stored Procedure (PL/SQL), one of the parameters is a blob, but when I execute the OracleCallableStatement I get this error:

**java.sql.SQLException: Data size bigger than max size for this type**

That is oh so very frustrating..

I have tried to do the following and fails...

```
oracleCallableStatement.setBinaryStream(3, new ByteArrayInputStream(someByteArray), someByteArray.length);
```

I get the same error with:

```
oracleCallableStatement.setBytes(3, someByteArray);
```

I also changed the oracle driver, since I read web pages like this:

http://www.coderanch.com/t/457770/JDBC/databases/java-sql-sqlexception-data-size

Says that there's a bug, I updated it to  ojdbc5.jar
From: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html

But the problem is persistent

The DB is an Oracle 11g
JavaEE is 1.5 running in Glassfish 2.1

Well, I guess that's it, my someByteArray is not bigger than 4Gb! it has a length of 38678

EDIT:
The exception is firing before the execute.. it fires when I set an attribute for the OracleCallableStatement

Portion of the stack trace:

```
at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:134)
at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:179)
at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTCItem.setArrayData(TTCItem.java:103)
at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBDataSetImpl.setBytesBindItem(DBDataSetImpl.java:2484)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setItem(OraclePreparedStatement.java:1224)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setBinaryStream(OraclePreparedStatement.java:2710)
```

EDIT

So, hello again, going to put this here... tell me if I´m doing wrong and I will delete it...

someByteArray was an array that was get from a someString.toByteArray()

That String was holding a representation of a (EDIT: used to say jpeg) PNG image encoded in Base64...

So, I used a method in sun.misc.BASE64Decoder to get the someByteArray from the someString...
then I used

```
oracleCallableStatement.setBinaryStream(3, new ByteArrayInputStream(someByteArray), someByteArray.length);
```

And it worked like a charm..

BUUUT... 
Usage of the classes in sun.misc is not recommended, read this for further information..

[work sun.misc.BASE64Encoder/Decoder for getting byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267036/work-sun-misc-base64encoder-decoder-for-getting-byte)

BUT!!!

That doesn't solve the mystery to why I was unable to put the first byte array into the parameters and the mystery of the cryptic exception "java.sql.SQLException: Data size bigger than max size for this type" ...

EDIT:

This error appeared again... this time everything was alright, I was decoding the base64 correctly, but "java.sql.SQLException: Data size bigger than max size for this type" kept returning...

EDIT:

It was the driver, I change it on the server and the app, and I redeployed and everything worked fine...

Comment: Also this looks like a more or less common error:
https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=9863886
http://dbaspot.com/oracle-server/68540-java-sql-sqlexception-bigger-type-length-than-maximum.html

Comment: Are you sure Glassfish is picking up your updated driver - that it doesn't have an older one that's taking precedence?

Comment: Yes, I double checked.

Comment: Also the exception is firing before the execute, it's firing the moment I set the parameter, Im going to edit my post...

Comment: @AlexPoole You were right... Glassfish was actually picking up the older driver...

Comment: Glad you got it sorted in the end *8-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was the driver, I  changed to ojdbc5.jar as I stated in my question, and I had to make sure that the web server picked the correct one and not the older one, as pointed by Alex Poole, and problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

***Not the answer***

You cannot keep the bytes of an image in a String (correctly). You could first encode the `byte[]` using Base64 into a String. Maybe though I misunderstand, and you did it correctly. *Check that you did log every exception.*

There are some other Base64 conversions besides the deprecated sun's version (which is not available in every JDK). In JavaEE:

```
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
String data = "...";
byte[] bytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(data);
String data = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(bytes);
```

Can't you store the data as binary blob, without base64 encoding? It'd at least save space.

An other error could be growing reused ByteArray's or something other trivial bug.

Comment: I edited my post, it was a PNG image not a jpeg, and, I am decoding it correctly from base64 to byte array...

Comment: Ahh, the image was delivered in Base64 (like form upload). So my answer is less helpful. Was a length given? `BLOB(102400)`? Though 4GB is max, there was a default of 2GB I thought.