# exception while uploading files larger than 32KB using an applet

Tags: java, exception, jdbc, applet

I have a webapp that uses Twain Scanner Applet to scan images and upload them to the DB.
My applet is locally installed.I have written a stored procedure to upload the file as a bfile and i am calling the procedure from the applet. Everything works fine when the file is less than 32KB but i get the following exception for files larger than 32KB

```
java.sql.SQLException: Data size bigger than max size for this type: 447596
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:124)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:161)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setRAW(OraclePreparedStatement.java:5329)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setBinaryStreamInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:6873)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.setBinaryStream(OracleCallableStatement.java:4497)
```

Please suggest me something.
I am using classes12.jar file for connecting to DB.

Also tell me which drivers are used by applets that are locally installed...the one that is present in web application or the one that is present on client machine?

Comment: Someone solved the same issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14859758/store-a-blob-from-java-to-bd-data-size-bigger-than-max-size-for-this-type-when by changing the driver. Could you tell us more about the DB/versions you use?

Comment: there is a static final int in bfile `MAX_CHUNK_SIZE` = 32512. you will probably have to use a different type

Comment: @StephaneM I use Oracle 10g Database...i saw the post linked by you and after changing the driver i dont get exceptions on JSP and Servlets but APPLET still throws exceptions

Comment: @Sionnach733 no there is no such thing in my code

Comment: @Pranav http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e13995/constant-values.html#oracle_sql_BFILE_MAX_CHUNK_SIZE is this the class you are using?

Comment: @Sionnach733 i convert the file object to FileInputStream and then i use setBinaryStream() of CallableStatement class to set the value...the StoredProcedure accepts a parameter "myfile IN BLOB" and does the rest

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

I solve it changing jdbc driver to `ojdbc14.jar`

Comment: I tried ojdbc14.jar but Applet still gives the same exception...did you have the same problem with an APPLET??

Comment: No I had it in servlet, but it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: my servlets dont give exception after changing the driver but APPLET still does...Does the applet use driver from webapp or from the client machine?????

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/bridge.html

refer this link and solve your problem. in JDK 1.8 now, jdbc is not being supported.

Why use ODBC at all?
The ideal is "Pure Java": no native code, no platform dependent features. But you may need to begin your development effort right away, without waiting for your DBMS to offer a Java-only JDBC driver. Partly native drivers, such as the JDBC-ODBC Bridge, let you create programs that easily adapt to Pure Java drivers as they become available.

Comment: Could you clarify a bit??

Comment: ODBC is purely java code so it's platform dependent as Java is open source but JDBC has used some of it's native API that might be not migrate with some features.

Comment: Okay so what do you suggest me to do?

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved...Driver was the issue...Oracle drivers in classes12.jar package had restrictions on upload size..i replaced it with ojdbc14.jar but my applet was still referring to the old file in some other directory..so changed the file over there and its working fine now..I posted the answer so that it may be useful to someone else..

Thank u everyone for their responses.