# java.sql.SQLException: Data size bigger than max size for this type OracleDB: 64852

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

I am using Oracle 11g with ojdbc14.jar as well as ojdb6.jar with Java 7 and trying to upload pdf in the blob field.
Project is on JDBC.

```
byte[] pdfData = byteArray....
cs.setBinaryStream(3, new ByteArrayInputStream(pdfData), pdfData.length);
```

But it throws exception **java.sql.SQLException: Data size bigger than max size for this type: 45160**. I am uploading on 45KB pdf file.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14859758.

Comment: Why are you using ojdbc14 (which is for the ancient Java 1.4!)? Also, neither ojdbc14, nor ojdbc6 is a version of the driver. Please specify the actual full version of the driver you're using and the full version of the Oracle database server.