# java.lang.IllegalStateException/ java.lang.ClassDefNotFoundError Adding External Jar to android project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, noclassdeffounderror, illegalstateexception

I'm trying to use some external jar files in my project but when I run the application it gives me ether  `java.lang.IllegalStateException` or `java.lang.ClassDefNotFoundError`. I have tried almost every method mentioned in here but couldn't found a solution. I'm using ADT version 22 and Android SDK version 17.

Here is the log:

```
8-26 16:50:21.022: E/AndroidRuntime(16642): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-26 16:50:21.022: E/AndroidRuntime(16642): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun.misc.BASE64Encoder
08-26 16:50:21.022: E/AndroidRuntime(16642):    at com.test.testlibs.MainActivity.convertMD5(MainActivity.java:48)
08-26 16:50:21.022: E/AndroidRuntime(16642):    at com.test.testlibs.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:30)
08-26 16:50:21.022: E/AndroidRuntime(16642):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4128)
08-26 16:50:21.022: E/AndroidRuntime(16642):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17142)
08-26 16:50:21.022: E/AndroidRuntime(16642):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
08-26 16:50:21.022: E/AndroidRuntime(16642):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-26 16:50:21.022: E/AndroidRuntime(16642):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
08-26 16:50:21.022: E/AndroidRuntime(16642):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
08-26 16:50:21.022: E/AndroidRuntime(16642):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-26 16:50:21.022: E/AndroidRuntime(16642):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-26 16:50:21.022: E/AndroidRuntime(16642):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
08-26 16:50:21.022: E/AndroidRuntime(16642):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
08-26 16:50:21.022: E/AndroidRuntime(16642):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and the class implimentation:

```
package com.test.testlibs;

import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

import com.test.testlibs.R.id;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(id.btnTest);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                convertMD5();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void convertMD5()
    {

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(id.txtTest);
        String text = textView.getText().toString();

        BASE64Encoder base64Encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
        String uname64 = base64Encoder.encode(text.getBytes());

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text+" "+uname64, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

I can email my project even if that's necessary too.

Comment: Have you check that if your Library project properly imported or Not and also available in workspace or not??

Comment: Yes I did. imported file is also in workspace

Comment: and your Class will be in sun.misc package??

Comment: Yes. Base64Class is inside the package.

Comment: you do realize there is a Base64 encoder already in android, right ? (unless you are targeting < 8, but who is still, these days?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a Sun(Oracle) specific class for Base64 encoding(sun.misc.BASE64Encoder). This file isn't going to be available on android.

I would suggest you use the android's [Base64](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html) class instead for encoding/decoding. As an additional benefit you would not even require to include any external library.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `.jar` file to **/libs** folder of your project.

Now right click the `.jar` file and *Build Path* > *Add to Build Path*.

Re build the project and run.

You may also look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/2267049/826657
 & this [How to get the JAR file for sun.misc.BASE64Encoder class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7102605/826657)

The BASE64ENCODER class is not available for all JVMs.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your workspace is having the JRE System Library in its classpath or not.

actually I can see in the exception stack that java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for sun.misc.BASE64Encoder and BASE64Encoder.class is present in rt.jar i.e. the part of JRE System library.

Comment: just Do a close project and open project and rebuild the project.

Answer (score 0):

```
08-26 16:50:21.022: E/AndroidRuntime(16642): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun.misc.BASE64Encoder
```

You are using `sun.misc.BASE64Encoder` for `Base64 encoding.` And it is not found whenever your application runs.

1. If you want to continue using it then try following.

   ```
   Right Click your project-->properties-->Java Build path-->Order and export tab

   then check the jars you are using.
   ```

2.If you are interested only in Base64 encoding then you can try `android.util.Base64` for `Base64` encoding.